# ZenDesk API cannot POST array inside an object

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, zendesk

I am using zafClient to perform requests as per this article:
https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/core-api/client_api#client.requestoptions

So far I am successful with GET requests and can fetch the information needed. Example:

```
zafClient.request({
    url: '/api/v2/macros.json',
    httpCompleteResponse: true,
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.responseJSON);  
  }, error => {
    console.log(error.responseText)
  })
```

but, when I perform POST operation, I am getting nasty error that I cannot fight.
here is post:

```
zafClient.request({
    url: '/api/v2/macros.json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      "macro": {
        'title': "Created Macro with API test",
        'actions': [{ "field": "subject", "value": "Change subjectline with API" }]
      }
    }
  }).then(res => console.log(res), error => console.log(error.responseText))
```

And here is the error.responseTest

```
{
  "error": {
    "title": "Invalid attribute",
    "message": "You passed an invalid value for the actions attribute. Invalid parameter: actions must be an array from api/v2/rules/macros/create"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in the post operation? if I log just the object "macro" I can see that attribute "actions" is an array, so the object "macro" is an exact object that I am fetching from API

Any ideas would be welcome as to what am I doing wrong.

Comment: If I add what's supposed to be an array into upper columns like so:
data: {
      "macro": {
        'title': "Created Macro with API test",
        'actions': '[{ "field": "subject", "value": "Change subjectline with API" }]'
      }
    }

Then in the Network tab > Headers > DataFormat I can see following:
macro[title]: Created with API test
macro[actions]: [{"field": "subject", "value": "change subject..."}]

But it still does not work and returns the same error - that Actions needs to be an array

Answer (score 0):

Now I know that I was supposed to JSON.Stringify passing data :)

```
zafClient.request({
    url: '/api/v2/macros.json',
    httpCompleteResponse: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      macro: {
        title: "Created Macro with API test",
        actions: [{ "field": "subject", "value": "Change subjectline with API" }]
      }
    })
  }).then(res => console.log(res), error => console.log(error.responseText))
```

First experience with HTTP requests